# Weird Html Css errors

Tags: html, css, browser

I've developed some htmls on asp.net platform.
But I got the different results when browsing in the Firefox and Google chrome. 
 [image]

Here are two subtitles, "Vence Vacation Rentals and Vence Hotels" and "Vence Vacations: Things to see while on vacation in Vence Provence"

The first one is h2 tag and the second is h3 tag.
I've applied same style to h2 and h3 tags.
But as you can see the image, the color is different a little.
Here is the html code and style for h2 and h3.

```
<div style="padding-bottom: 10px;margin-left:20px;">  
<h2 class='titles'>
Vence Vacation Rentals and Vence Hotels
                             <br />  
 </h2>
</div>


 <h3 class='titles'>
  Vence Vacations: Things to see while on vacation in Vence Provence
 </h3>
```

For style

```
.titles {
color: #154890 !important;
font-family: Verdana;
font-size: 18px;
font-weight:500;
}
```

And the style for h3 is embedded in the h3 tag.
I couldn't know why I get the different color for two titles.
It seems that the h2 color is darker than h3.
Please help me.
Thanks.  (Please forgive my low english level)

Comment: why apply the style in h3 with in html tag..use with `h2,h3{}` in css.or tell if you have any external libraries of css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are aware that you have not sent font for h3? Also, it's not best practice to embed style in the html tags. Do you have any other stylesheets loading that may interfere?

Comment: So I've created css class for the h3 tag.

Comment: And? Did it change anything? What if you add `!important` to it? (This should override any external stylesheets you are importing.)

Comment: And I've applied that class to the h3 (h3 class='titles') But I got the same result.

Comment: Do both have the same font? Antialiasing may change how the colour looks. Also, does !important change it?

Comment: I found that the same result has caused between h1 and h2 , h3.

Comment: Please provide full css. Something might be overriding it. Again, try `!important`

Comment: H1 is the darkest and h2 is darker than h3.

Comment: How could I provide ? In the comment or to edit the question?

Comment: That's probably browser defaults overriding. The h tags do have specific heirarchy. You could try making them <p> tags, that way there's no browser defaults.

Provide in edit to question.

Comment: I've changed. You could see the result for that in your browser. That's really weird.

Comment: Note for Manmeet Gill. Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you do figure it out, make sure you edit the post! :)

Answer (score 0):

According to the perspective angle, you could get the different sense about the color.
So you could check the color by html inspector.